# Simple Calculation throw NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception, double, awt

This is my simple calculation.

```
private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(totalcost.getText());
    double t2 = Double.parseDouble(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString());
    double t = t1 * (t2 / 100);
    double ToT = t1 - t;
    Total.setText(ToT + "");
}
```

when I run and select the jComboBox Item,I used jCombox selectedItem **as 5%;**

I get this an exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5%"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Dresss.pre_order.jComboBox2ActionPerformed(pre_order.java:586)
    at Dresss.pre_order.access$1500(pre_order.java:13)
```

what is the error of this code. Thanx in advanced.

Comment: You have a string `"5%"` which cannot be parsed as a `double`.

Comment: `"5%"` can't be parsed as a `double`. You'll need to write your own method to interpret percentage strings.

Comment: Thnx both of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5%"
```

`5%` is not a parsable double, you have to convert it manually:

```
Double d;
String string = "5%";
if (string.endsWith("%")) {
    string.replace("%", "");
    d = Double.parseDouble(string);
    d /= 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna use t1 not a persentage, like number use this:

```
double t1= Double.parseDouble(totalcost.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

If you wanna the persentage use:

```
double t1= Double.parseDouble(totalcost.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", ""))/100;
```

Comment: I believe this works fine only when the input format is `xx%`, if the input is `5` or `5.0`, it will cause bugs.

Answer (score 1):

maybe that can help you :

substring(x,y): function to get a part of string from index x to index y.

indexof :function to get index of a character in string.

```
String s="5%";
        double t=Double.parseDouble(s.substring(0, s.indexOf("%")))/100;
        System.out.println(""+t);
```

Output:

```
0.05
```

`